# RegEx is not doing what I want

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string

I want to retreive a part of a string, my question is if I can get the correct string without touching the matched string (substring or splitting), I know is easy to do a split/substring but I want to know if I can improve the RegEx to do the job itself.

This is the String:

```
<h3 class="btl"><a href="http://post-hardcore.ru/music/2689-drifter-in-search-of-something-more-ep-2013.html">Drifter - In Search of Something More [EP] (2013)</a></h3>
```

This is what I get:

```
>Drifter - In Search of Something More [EP] (2013)</a><
```

This is what I want to get:

```
Drifter - In Search of Something More [EP] (2013)
```

This is my RegEx:

```
Dim RegEx_AlbumName As New Regex(">[^<].*<")

MsgBox(RegEx_AlbumName.Match(Line).Groups(0).ToString)
```

I don't want to do this:

```
AlbumName = RegEx_AlbumName.Match(Line).Groups(0).ToString.Substring(1).Replace("</a><", "")
```

**EDIT:** Note that the parentheses word "(2013)" may not be in other strings that I need to match.

Comment: If it is valid XHTML you're trying to read you might be able to use VB XML literals and just get the content of <a>.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use regular expressions instead of XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex was close. The `[^<]` worked only for the first character after `>` the `.*` eat up any character until the last `<`, because it is **greedy**. Try this:

```
Dim RegEx_AlbumName As New Regex(">([^<]+?)<")

MsgBox(RegEx_AlbumName.Match(Line).Groups(1).ToString)
```

The `?` tell the regex to match the shortest possible string. Only in this case I think it will work without it too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working, this is what I get in the regex group: "><"

Comment: @ElektroHacker Right, that's because of the `*` which allows zero length string, instead it must be `+`. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks now it works better than my original regex but the question is if I can tell your regex to not show the first and last "><" chars.

Comment: @ElektroHacker Yes, more corrections made, note now the use of `group(1)`